# I am looking for an affordable outdoor security PoE camera from a western brand

Tags: video-camera, poe

I am looking for an outdoor security video camera. Requirements:

- The camera was designed by a western brand (software & electric). It doesn't matter where it was manufactured. (I don't want to talk about the reasons.)
- It supports Power over Ethernet (PoE)
- It is affordable (below 220€)
- It has night vision (infra red, no visible light)

Optional features:

- supported by Synology surveillance station
- SD card slot

Arlo don't have PoE devices. Axis is too expensive. Annke don't design the devices themselves. They are rebranded Hickvision cameras and they come from China.